# how to manipulate argument in VB Script?

Tags: vbscript, arguments, shortcut

im trying to automate shortcut creation, but have no idea how to get filename from argument. code is run as:

cscript shortcut.vbs "c:\folder\targetfile.ext"

```
Set objFS=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
strFile= objArgs(0)
Set objFile = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFile)
Set objFile = objFS.GetFile(strFile)
WScript.Echo objFile.Path 

Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
sLinkFile = "c:\myfolder\myshortcut.lnk" 
Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) 
oLink.TargetPath = objFile.Path 
oLink.Save
```

is it possible in the following line to combine user specified folder and automatically generated filename from argument with .lnk extension

```
sLinkFile = "c:\myfolder\myshortcut.lnk"
```

to something like this:

```
sLinkFile = "c:\myfolder\" + filenamefromargument(e.g targetfile) + ".lnk"
```

thx in advance :)

Comment: `sLinkFile = "c:\myfolder\" & objArgs(0) & ".lnk"`. Don't use plus, it only works for compatibility with older basics and if both strings contain numbers they will be added not concatenated.

Comment: lol. i didnt intent to use it for real :) it was just a "artistic" view how it should go

Comment: For true programming efficiency use `strFile` rather than objArgs(0). `strfile` is a variable therefore it is easy for the CPU to reference by it's memory address in the stack. `objArgs(0)` means `objArgs.item(0)` which is a function call via COM. Therefore a new stack is created, the return address, parameters, and local variables (to `item` method) are put onto the stack, then code is run. Then it's all undone leaving the old stack frame the current one. This is a lot slower. The principal if using a property more than once, stick in a variable.

Comment: unfortunately both of your solutions didnt work, neither with sLinkFile = "c:\myfolder\" & objArgs(0) & ".lnk" nor sLinkFile = "c:\myfolder\" & strfile & ".lnk". sorry for getting annoying but i have zero knowledge about scripts and stuff and even formatting comment here :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Noodles first suggestion will work - and his second suggestion just means you should assign `strFile = objArgs(0)` before you use it.

You're just confusing everyone by your 'pseudo examples'
You first specify `"c:\folder\targetfile.ext"` as argument
then `sLinkFile = "c:\myfolder\myshortcut.lnk"` where I think you meant `sLinkFile = "c:\myfolder\myshortcut.ext"`

The second piece you need is to look at FileSystemObject methods to extract the folder and base name - then append your extension

Something like:

**After** `strFile= objArgs(0)`

**Insert this code:**

```
With objFS    
   strLinkFile = .GetParentFolderName(strFile) & .GetBaseName(strFile) & ".lnk"
End With
```